# Unable to call shell script from apache httpd

Tags: apache, shell

I am trying to call shell script from 000-default.conf inside /etc/httpd/sites-available.

The 000-default.conf file content is :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        CustomLog "| sh /scratch/user/test.sh" custom_user_tracking
    </VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf has below content added:

```
ServerName localhost
LogFormat "%t [%h] [%m] [%U] [%B] [%b] [%D] [%q] [%s] [%{Referer}i] [%{User-Agent}i]" custom_user_tracking
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-available/*.conf
```

I have kept a dummy html file inside /var/www/html/
Content of index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When ever I hit http://localhost:80 the shell script is not called at all. The shell script is executable and it just prints "Hello World".

But when I call apache kafka binary from 000-default.conf file then it works properly.

Modified 000-default.conf file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        CustomLog "| [HOME_DIR_KAFKA]/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic access-log --broker- list <Remote_host_ip>:9092" custom_user_tracking
    </VirtualHost>
```

Now when I click on http://localhost:80 then message is send in remote kafka server.

Can any one help here how can I call shell script from apache httpd?

Answer (score 0):

Consider making  the test.sh script executable using "shebang" ($!), instead of using sh.

```
000-default.conf :
    CustomLog "| /scratch/user/test.sh" custom_user_tracking

/scratch/user/test.sh   
    #! /bin/sh
    ...
```

Alternatively run 'sh' using full path 
        CustomLog "| /bin/sh /scratch/user/test.sh" custom_user_tracking

Also, double check the execute permission on /scratch/user/test.sh, and the permission on the folder. https is usually running as non-privileged account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now the script is called from the conf file.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which approach did you use ? (The '#!' line, or the /bin/sh)

Comment: Now I am facing another issue. The shell script is called in 5s interval automatically. Ideally when we will hit http://localhost:80 then the script should be called. But its calling internally in 5 s interval. I have verified the /etc/crontab and it contains below content:                                                              
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

Comment: Consider sharing "test.sh". Does it follow the requirement of the custom log directive ?

Comment: Here is the content of /etc/httpd/sites-available/000-dafult.conf

Answer (score 0):

Here is the content of send_message.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh


PRIVATE_KEY=$1
HOST=$2
TOPIC_NAME=$3
MESSAGE=$4

echo "OCI VM IP : $HOST"
echo "PRIVATE KEY : $PRIVATE_KEY"
echo "TOPIC-NAME: $TOPIC_NAME"
echo "MESSAGE: $MESSAGE"

## Run Cmd in vm
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -i $PRIVATE_KEY opc@$HOST /bin/bash << EOF
       sudo su
       echo $MESSAGE | [HOME_DIR]/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list [VM_IP]:9092 --topic $TOPIC_NAME
EOF
```

And content of /etc/httpd/sites-available/000-dafult.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    CustomLog "| /home/opc/send_message.sh /home/opc/dev2oci.key 100.111.69.61 access-log apache-httpd" custom_user_tracking
</VirtualHost>
```

The message is sent in topi access_log for every 5s interval. Though the http://localhost:80 is not triggered from browser.

If I replace the CustomLog with below entry:

```
CustomLog "| [HOME_DIR]/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic access-log --broker-list [VM_IP]:9092" custom_user_tracking
```

Then message is sent on triggering http://localhost:80 from browser.

Can anyone let me know what I am missing here.