# how to disable auto refresh in apache httpd

Tags: apache, shell, httpd.conf

I am trying to call shell script from 000-default.conf inside /etc/httpd/sites-available.

The 000-default.conf file content is :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        CustomLog "| /bin/sh /scratch/user/test.sh" custom_user_tracking
    </VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf has below content added:

```
    ServerName localhost
    LogFormat "%t [%h] [%m] [%U] [%B] [%b] [%D] [%q] [%s] [%{Referer}i] [%{User-Agent}i]" custom_user_tracking
    IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
    IncludeOptional sites-available/*.conf
```

I have kept a dummy html file inside /var/www/html/ Content of index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When ever I hit http://localhost:80 the shell script is called. The shell script is executable and it just prints "Hello World".

But the script is auto called in 5s interval though the url  http://localhost:80 is not triggered from the browser.

Can any one help here how can I disable auto refresh in apache httpd?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to call shell script from apache httpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143754/unable-to-call-shell-script-from-apache-httpd)

Comment: Consider sharing the test.sh script. Does it follow CustomLog requirements ?